# "Son of fish knows how to swim"

Tags: significado

Could you please help me out and explain the commonly used connotation for the saying "Son of fish knows how to swim?" While I know the primary meaning, the connotation is still unclear for me... Is it OK to use to compliment someone? Or rather to give an attitude?

Answer (score 2):

In pt-br there's a similar saying, *Filho de peixe, peixinho é." (literally "A fish's kid is a little fish."), which simply means that a kid is like their parent, in a **neutral** way - so it can be used to both compliment or criticize.

Corresponding sayings in English include:

- Like father, like son. /  Like mother, like daughter.
- The apple doesn’t fall far from the tree.